# Socket connection based on mac address in c#

Tags: c#, macos, sockets

Ok so this question comes about from my use of cognex dataman series cameras.
In this case the camera always acts as a server and anything connecting to it as a client.
When we get these cameras they are always on a weird subnet. 
for example: 192.168.5.x and my office and my workstation is on 192.168.2.x
So my limited networking knowledge says I should not be able to talk to the camera.

The weird thing is the dataman camera setup tool allows me to connect to it via mac address and I was wondering how that worked under the covers.

Is there some way to open up a socket via mac address alone, bypassing the ip-address all together?

The reason I ask is because I work on an audit system that uses say 3 cameras per machine and say 10 machines in a plant. that is 40 ip-addresses in total with the cameras also visible.

It would be awesome to free up those 30 cameras by putting them on some other subnet and having the software talk to it via mac address...

This post most likely exposes my lack of networking knowledge but I didn't find a good answer to my question in the series of tubes.

Anyway cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*192.168.5.x and my office and my workstation is on 192.168.2.x So my limited networking knowledge says I should not be able to talk to the camera*

This is true, but you can setup a server (or if thats to expensive; a computer with 2 network cards will do too) to connect them, although, unless you have a skilled IT person who can easily do this I suggest this should be your last option.

I'd say why not find out why the cameras connect to the strange subnet? I've found a online manual which described this:

> A reader can also generate a Cognex device configuration (.cdc) file,which stores the set of runtime parameters plus any identificationdata, such as the name of the device, its IP address, subnet mask, andso on. Cognex recommends generating a device configuration file foreach reader to allow you to restore a reader to its operating state withminimal effort

[Source: Google cached document - DataMan 300 Series Quick Reference Guide](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aONafGXPKkI0J%3awww.cognex.cn/Support/Downloads/Download.aspx?d=2450&l=2052%20&cd=1&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=nl)

It seems there is **.cdc** file stored on the cameras that contain information about such information like networking configurations. I guess you should look deeper into that.

*Is there some way to open up a socket via mac address alone, bypassing the ip-address all together?*

To create a connection using **just** a MAC address isn't possible, especially not using a socket connection as they only support IP addresses.

Although, whenever you fixed the subnet problem, the cameras will appear in the [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) (Address Resolution Protocol) table that the [CMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt) (Command Prompt) of Windows offers.

`ARP` is one of the commands that the CMD listens to, it will display all IP and MAC addresses (together) of all devices inside your interface (your interface is 192.168.2.X).

C# can start processes, like the CMD, and it can also pass arguments:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "arp -a");
```

[This](http://www.mostthingsweb.com/2011/11/reading-arp-entries-with-c/) link will help you executing the ARP command in CMD and getting its results using C#.

Good luck!

Comment: Fantastic, I suspected no connection with Mac would be possible but this confirms it. Very useful thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign 2 IP addresses to a network card and connect to both networks at the same time. Just make sure your default gateway is on the right network